# op-amp bias current measurement

Tags: operational-amplifier, bandwidth, gain-bandwidth-product

I am trying to measure the offset voltage and bias current using the technique below (Figure 2 and Figure 3)
[op-amp servo-loop](https://www.analog.com/en/resources/analog-dialogue/articles/simple-op-amp-measurements.html)
My question is: can I use [NJM4580](https://docs.rs-online.com/aae1/0900766b813e42a5.pdf) as the op-amp under test and use the op-amp [ADA4510-2](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ada4510-2.pdf) as the Axillary op-amp? question arises from the fact that the axillary has a lower bandwidth compared to the DUT. But I think because bias current and offset voltage are DC parameters, I can use a lower bandwidth axillary?

Answer (score 0):

1. That circuit is way more complicated than it needs to be. It is intended for the measurement of many parameters with a single setup. Unless the parameters are very unusual (say, an extremely small bias current) a single op amp circuit with two variations of resistors will be enough for the measurement.
2. The spec sheet HAS these parameters. Are you planning to select op amps for a specific application? Better procedure is to just design for worst case.